# Why we need to invert crc? In which cases we need to do this?

Tags: protocols, crc

Why we need to invert crc? In which cases we need to do this? (invert mean `crc = ~crc`)

Is it defence from zero cases (when whole message is consists of zeros)?

How it helps in this case?

Comment: why do you want to reverse the crc?

Comment: Where did you find a reference to "reverse crc"?

Answer (score 1):

You mean invert, or take the one's complement. (Reverse would mean swapping the order of the bits, undoing a CRC calculation, or reverse-engineering the CRC parameters.)

That is done when the CRC parameters are defined that way. See [this list of CRCs](http://reveng.sourceforge.net/crc-catalogue/all.htm), where those with `xorout` defined as all 1's are inverting the CRC before return.

A common example is when the initial register contents, `init` is also all 1's, so the final `xorout` then makes the CRC of an empty string zero. The `init` being non-zero is how you "defend" against the all-zeros message case, which assures that every zero changes the CRC. The `xorout` then just provides the nicety of a CRC of an empty message being zero. There are CRC definitions there with zero `xorout` (no invert or exclusive-or at the end), but a non-zero `init`, which provides that defense as well.

Comment: You absolutely right i mean invert. Thanks for your answer.