# How do I use this CRC-32C C# library?

Tags: c#, crc, crc32

I've downloaded this library https://github.com/robertvazan/crc32c.net for my project I'm working on. I need to use CRC in a part of my project so I downloaded the library as it is obviously going to be much faster than anything I'm going to write in the near future.

I have some understanding of how crc works, I once made a software implementation of it (as a part of learning) that worked, but I have got to be doing something incredibly stupid while trying to get this library to work and not realize it. No matter what I do, I can't seem to be able to get crc = 0 even though the arrays were not changed.

Basically, my question is, how do I actually use this library to check for integrity of a byte array?

The way I understand it, I should call `Crc32CAlgorithm.Compute(array)` once to compute the crc the first time and then call it again on an array that has the previously returned value appended (I've tried to append it as well as set last 4 bytes of the array to zeroes before putting the returned value there) and if the second call returns 0 the array was unchanged.

Please help me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

EDIT: It doesn't work right when I do this: (yes, I realize linq is very slow, this is just an example)

```
        using(var hash = new Crc32CAlgorithm())
        {
            var array = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
            var crc = hash.ComputeHash(array);
            var arrayWithCrc = array.Concat(crc).ToArray();
            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", hash.ComputeHash(arrayWithCrc)));
        }
```

Console outputs: 199 75 103 72

Comment: A CRC adds bytes at end of original data.  So if you have 96 bytes the results with CRC32 is 100 bytes.  Then if you computer the CRC of the 100 bytes you usually will get all zeroes or all ones depending on the CRC properties you are using.  The  same algorithm (method) is use the Computer and Check.  the only difference is the computer calculates over 96 bytes while the Check computers over 100 bytes.  See : http://www.sunshine2k.de/coding/javascript/crc/crc_js.html.  See the link on page to "Understanding and Implementing"

Comment: @jdweng Thank you for taking your time to answer. If you would please look at the edit of my question, I've done pretty much that (at least I think) and it doesn't work for me :/

Comment: You may have to invert the CRC, then append it, and expect FFFFFFFF instead of zero

Comment: @harold Nice! It works that way. I've never heard about inverting the crc and expecting FFFFFFFF, and I've had multiple classes on crc at my university. Why does it work like that all the while not working the "usual" way?

Comment: @Petrusion there is some explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39385468/555045). In this case, since the CRC is already inverted, you're really un-inverting it to make the math work out again, and then the expected result is FFFFFFFF because that's also inverted

Comment: From the Gihub I found this : uint crc = Crc32CAlgorithm.Compute(array);  So the algorithm is returning an int while your code is expecting a byte array.  found documentation you have to use the library Append method.  See : https://crc32c.machinezoo.com/#net

Comment: The CRC is a shift register with feedback.   Depending if you feed into the LSB a 1 or 0 will determine if you get a zero of a 1 as result.

Comment: @jdweng - Mark Adler's answer explains this, If a CRC is post complemented, then recalculating CRC on data + CRC results in a constant but non-zero value.

Comment: @harold - Mark Adler's answer explains this, If a CRC is post complemented, then recalculating CRC on data + CRC results in a constant but non-zero value.

Comment: @rcgldr : Mark's solution is more complicated.  When you computer the CRC you start with a seed value like a pseudo random generator and then get a CRC.  When you do the check you should end up with the initial seed value.  You can look at the computation like division.  If you take 14 and divide by 4 you get 3 with a remainder of of 2.  The CRC is the two.  So if you then take 3 and multiply by 4 you get 12.  Then subtract 12 from 14 you get the same CRC of 2.  The CRC algorithm is really a division with the CRC being the remainder.

Comment: @jdwend No, you don't end up with the "initial seed value".

Comment: @jdweng - the effect of post complementing the CRC is to XOR the CRC with 0xffffffff before storing it. The end result is recalculating the CRC is the same as a CRC32C modified so that the initial CRC is 0x00000000, and is not post complemented, and the data is 0xffffffff, which results in a CRC of `0x48674bc7` .

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to append a CRC to a message and compute the CRC of that in order to check a CRC. Just compute the CRC on the message on one end, send that CRC along with the message, compute CRC on *just* the message on the other end (not including the sent CRC), and then *compare* the CRC you computed to the one that was sent with the message.

They should be equal to each other. That's all there is to it. That works for *any* hash you might use, not just CRCs.

If you feel deeply compelled to make use of the lovely mathematical property of CRCs where computing the CRC on the message with its CRC appended gives a specific result, you can. You have to append the CRC bits in the correct order, and you need to look for the "residue" of the CRC, which may not be zero.

In your case, you are in fact appending the bits in the correct order (by appending the bytes in little-endian order), and the result you are getting is the correct residue for the CRC-32C. That residue is `0x48674bc7`, which separated into bytes, in little-endian order, and then converted into decimal is your `199 75 103 72`.

You will find that if you take *any* sequence of bytes, compute the CRC-32C of that, append that CRC to the sequence in little-endian order, and compute the CRC-32C of the sequence plus CRC, you will *always* get `0x48674bc7`.

However that's smidge slower than just comparing the two CRC's, since now you have to compute a CRC on four more bytes than before. So, really, there's no need to do it this way.

Comment: I'm wondering about relative difference in speed of using CRC32C instruction on 4 more bytes, then compare immediate, versus CRC32 on just data and compare with memory (both implementations fetch the same amount of memory, so then it is a case of differences in the uops involved). If the code is using pshufb + pclmulqdq to operate on 16 bytes at a time in parallel, and if the appended CRC is included in the last group of bytes processed, there is virtually no overhead, because the fetches are fixed in size using movdqu or movdqa into xmm registers.

Comment: @Mark Adler : You solution is making too complicated.  First the CRC is always added to the end of the message.  So on the receive end calculation the CRC on the data you have to remove the CRC (or subtract the CRC length from the message) and then do a comparison of calculated CRC and against the receive CRC.  Much simpler to calculate the CRC all all the receive data and then check for CRC equal zero or one depending on the type of CRC being used.

Comment: @jdweng Subtracting four is not "too complicated". It's _less_ complicated, in terms of the number of operations, than computing a CRC on an additional four bytes. By the way, it's not "equal zero or one". In that case you compare to the expected residual, which is `0x48674bc7`.

Comment: @rcgldr Ok, so for arbitrary packet lengths, one out of 16 times there will be no overhead for including the CRC when using that particular instruction on that particular processor.

Comment: @MarkAdler - For pshufb, it's more than one out of 16, the last fetch is 16 bytes, but it could be anywhere from 1 to 12 bytes of data + 4 bytes of CRC. In the case of crc32c, the same amount of data is fetched, and the sequence is crc32c, compare immediate (or with register), versus compare with memory. I don't know if the memory access hides the overhead of crc32c + compare immediate (or compare register) versus compare memory.